# How can I make an ATM machine with PHP by using only one loop and an array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have made an ATM machine in PHP, but I have used 4 for-loops. I want to use only one loop and an array. This is my code:

```
private function Atm() {
    $nAmount = $_POST['txtATM'];

    $nFifty = 0;
    for ($V=0; $V < $nAmount; $V+=50) { 
        $nFifty++;
    }
        if ($V > $nAmount) {
            $V-=50;
            $nFifty-=1;
        }

    $nTwenty = 0;
    for ($T=$V; $T < $nAmount; $T+=20) { 
        $nTwenty++;
    }
        if ($T > $nAmount) {
            $T-=20;
            $nTwenty-=1;
        }

    $nTen = 0;
    for ($t=$T; $t < $nAmount; $t+=10) { 
        $nTen++;
    }
        if ($t > $nAmount) {
            $t -= 10;
            $nTen-=1;
        }

    $nFive = 0;
    for ($v=$t; $v < $nAmount; $v+=5) { 
        $nFive++;
    }
        if ($v > $nAmount) {
            $v-=5;
            $nFive-=1;
        }

    echo "You will get: ";
    echo "$nFifty times fifty, $nTwenty times twenty, $nTen times ten and $nFive times five. ";
}
```

Can someone help me to find a solution to rewrite this code with just one loop and an array?

Comment: This is not how SO works. Please take the [tour] and read the [ask] guide.

Comment: What happend is the sum is 11? (Not divided by 5?)

Comment: private function check() {

 if (isset($_POST['btnATM'])) {

  $nAmount = $_POST['txtATM'];
  
  if ($nAmount < 5 || $nAmount % 5 !=0) {
   echo "error";
  }

  elseif (strpos($nAmount, ",") || strpos($nAmount, ".") || !is_numeric($nAmount)) {
   echo "only numbers";
  }
 
  elseif ($nAmount > 500) {
   echo "limit is 500";
  }else {
   return $this->Atm();
  }
 }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with 1 loop (I prefer while in this case):

```
$arr = array(50, 20, 10, 5);
$name = array("fifty", "twenty", "ten", "five");
$v = 105;
while ($v && count($arr)) {
    $currentBill = array_shift($arr);
    $change[] = intval($v / $currentBill);
    $v = $v % $currentBill;
}
for ($i = 0; $i < count($change); $i++)
    echo $change[$i] . " of ". $name[$i] .", ";
```

I recommend add error checking at the beginning for not divided-able by 5 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I would calculate the modulo to check for a valid denomination and then repeatedly do an integer devision in a loop setting an array with the strings *n times denomination*, then join comma separated, except the last one which is separated by `'and'`.

The modulo operation result is the rest of an integer division. If there's a rest on the smallest denomination, the amount cannot be paid.

The integer devision gives you the count of a specific denomination. We begin with the greatest. The remnant is processed with the next smaller denomination.

```
function Atm(int $amount)
{
  $denominations = [50 => 'fifty', 20 => 'twenty', 10 => 'ten' , 5 => 'five'];

  if($amount <= 0 || $amount % array_key_last($denominations))
    return 'Amount cannot be paid. $5 is the smallest denomination.' . PHP_EOL;

  $arr = [];

  foreach($denominations as $denomination => $name)
  {
    $amount -= $denomination * $count = (int) ($amount / $denomination);
    if($count)
      $arr[] = "$count times $name";
  }

  return 'You will get: '
       . (1 === count($arr) ? $arr[0] : implode(', ', array_splice($arr, 0, -1)) . ' and ' . $arr[0])
       . '.' . PHP_EOL;
}

var_dump(Atm(5));
var_dump(Atm(105));
var_dump(Atm(115));
var_dump(Atm(116));
```

Output:

```
string(28) "You will get: 1 times five.
"
string(46) "You will get: 2 times fifty and 1 times five.
"
string(59) "You will get: 2 times fifty, 1 times ten and 1 times five.
"
string(52) "Amount cannot be paid. $5 is the smallest denomination.
"
```

TODO: You should write a routine to output 'once', 'twice', 'n time' or find another expression like '1 bill', '2 bills'.